# Do linear transformations on curves defined by polynomials preserve tangents?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a curve $C$ defined by $F(X,Y) = 0$ where $F$ is a  polynomial. Suppose $l$ is a curve that is tangent to $C$ at some point $P$ and that $M$ is an invertible linear transformation  $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Define a new curve $C'$ to be the image of $C$ under $M$ and a new line $l'$ to be the image of $l$ under the $M$. Is it necessarily the case that $l'$ is tangent to $C'$?

Comment: Yes, the order of contact between geometric objects will be preserved by diffeomorphisms (which a linear transformation certainly is).  In the instance of tangency, you can see this thinking of  parametrizing your curves to have a common tangent vector and then thinking about the pushforward of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order of contact between geometric objects will be preserved by diffeomorphisms (which a linear transformation certainly is).  In the instance of tangency, you can see this thinking of  parametrizing your curves to have a common tangent vector and then thinking about the pushforward of $M$. -- [THW](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644116/do-linear-transformations-on-curves-defined-by-polynomials-preserve-tangents#comment1359564_644116)